# Firefox tries to download .php file on local apache server instead of render result

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I've been trying to install both Apache and PHP from source so they work together, as a "to see if I can" project.

However, when I try to load a "localhost" file, firefox just starts downloading the .php page instead of opening it.

I'm pretty sure I've added the correct handlers in ./conf/httpd.conf, they are shown below

```
#configure for php
AddHandler php-script .php

AddType text/html .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source phps
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

I've also tried replacing

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

with

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 php
```

and

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

and

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php php
```

Comment: download the php file in your browser and see if it is php or html

Comment: You have `mod_php` installed and working, right?

Comment: @leftclickben, if that would have been installed by either PHP or Apache2 source-code, then yes, if it's another package, where would I find it?

Comment: @leftclickben, after a spot of googling, I realize that means the php module is being loaded by apache. The line "LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so" is in my httpd.conf and there are no errors about it on the command line, so I'm assuming that means mod_php is installed and working.

Comment: You should have a `libphp5.so` file in your modules directory, for example on my system in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`.  You also need to have `php5.conf` and `php5.load` in `mods-available` and linked to `mods-enabled` (usually using `a2enmod` utility) -- this is where the `SetHandler` stuff is on my machine.  But the important thing is the `libphp5.so` file and that it is being loaded by Apache using a `LoadModule` instruction.

Comment: @leftclickben, there is no mods-available or mods-enabled directory in my /usr/lib/apache2 or /usr/lib/apache2/modules. However, libphp5.so is there, and there's a LoadMOdule line for it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the `mods-available` and `mods-enabled` files are in the config directory, usually `/etc/apache2` or maybe `/etc/httpd`.  However this structure is not necessarily in place on your system.   The `*.so` files live (normally) in the `/usr/lib` directory.  But if you have a `LoadModule` and no errors, I think that part is fine.

Comment: Apache seems to have installed completely in one directory, so no config directories. But as I said, no error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured apache to load php module?
have a look here:
http://www.petefreitag.com/item/516.cfm

Comment: Between conf/httpd.conf and conf/php.conf there seems to be the relavent code there. But still no php output.

Comment: Wait, after some tweaking and bug-fixing of my following of the above instructions, it seems to be working okay. Thanks for the answer :)